# Modal Window on Full Page instead of Div

Tags: modal-dialog

[image: Calendar monthly in different Iframes]

I have a situation where Modal window is opening on clicking calendar event in each div only. I want to open the events in full page modal window instead.How can i do this. I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Means,.. do you want to open full Calendar List View on Modal Dialog ?

Comment: I want that if i click on an event in any calendar, i want the modal dialog to open in full modal dialog instead of opening in that particular div.

Comment: BTW, is below answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

By your given image, I predict that you are working with **multiple iFrames** on the page (your DIVs behave like it).

iFrame itself is full page where you can display the another page's content in it. When you are opening the Modal Dialog in it than it will bind to that particular iFrame only.

You can achieve it by handling the event of the link of event in calendar & open it by code without the parameter called `isDlg=1` in the URL.

Comment: isDlg=1 is the parameter indeed. I believe you have 2 options. 1. Try to change the new/edit form settings inside list settings where you can disable the modal option. 2. DIRTY option would be write Jquery to get all the links in the calendar container & alter their href to remove the parameter